# how to pass oAuth1.0 consumer key and consumer secret parameters in axios?

Tags: api, react-native, woocommerce, axios

I want to get products from woocommerce wordpress website it needs to send consumer key and secret, but how to send them with axios in react native?? 
Here is example from postman>
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add interceptor to Axios using [axios-oauth-1.0a](https://github.com/dobesv/axios-oauth-1.0a)

Sample code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import addOAuthInterceptor from "axios-oauth-1.0a";

// Create a client whose requests will be signed
const client = axios.create();

// Add interceptor that signs requests
addOAuthInterceptor(client, {
// OAuth consumer key and secret
 key: "xxx",
 secret: "yyy",
// HMAC-SHA1 and HMAC-SHA256 are supported
algorithm: "HMAC-SHA1",
});

// Now send requests to the OAuth 1.0a service using that client
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete code? including API call